# Integer value promotion to unsigned int vs signed int in c

Tags: c, if-statement, integer, integer-promotion

I have two c codes, the difference between them is that one uses char and one uses int, as follows,

***First:***

if case is true

```
int x = -1;
unsigned int y = 2;
if(x>y)
```

***Second:***

the if case is false

```
char x = -1;
unsigned char y = 2;
if(x>y)
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: be aware that the signedness of `char` is implementation-defined.

Comment: @Barmar the dup is about comparing for equality.

Comment: Dupe looks like it is C++ even though there is also a C tag.

Comment: @WeatherVane I think the promotion rules are the same for equality and inequality tests.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons C and C++ are similar in this area.

Comment: Basically everything is first expanded to int if both ranges are representable in an int, else unsigned int. In the first case both are converted to unsigned int, in the second to int

Comment: In the second case, both values can be promoted to `int` without loss so the comparison works correctly. In the first case, they cannot so are converted to `unsigned int`, and the negative value is converted by the implementation to a large positive value. C11 **§6.3.1.1.2** says *If an `int` can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an `int`; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`. These are called the **integer promotions**. All other types are unchanged by the integer promotions.*

Comment: @Barmar I thought there was a preference to separate C and C++ questions to fight the narrative that "C/C++" is a language and that we want them to be treated separately to avoid the issues that come along with assuming what is true with one is true of another.

Comment: @Barmar but it does not answer this question: why the comparison breaks.

Comment: @WeatherVane this one does

Comment: @AnttiHaapala yes is more relevant.

Comment: @WeatherVane if you do have sth to add then please do edit Lundin's answer or add another one ;)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala why would I do that to an exemplary answer? I posted my comment before you added the dupe (and before I saw your earlier comment - I was typing).

Comment: @WeatherVane well it might be sth that the exemplary answer is missing :d